# How to create a context sensitive right-click menu in svelte?

Tags: contextmenu, svelte, right-click

I found [this example](https://svelte.dev/repl/3a33725c3adb4f57b46b597f9dade0c1?version=3.25.0) to create a right-click menu in Svelte, which works fine. It is bound on the whole document body using svelte:body.

What I would like to have is a right-click menu only in context of specific Component e.g. a list of steps, where with the menu I could have actions like "mark all items in the list before" or "mark all items after the current step as red".

Answer (score 5):

OK, I had to define the Context Menu in the Step component itself to make it work.

Here's my solution: https://svelte.dev/repl/16c8a02ebaa9425a9cbbfd66feea1a9e?version=3.29.0

Comment: It is nice, but you can open a few menus at the same time.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I get the standard OS context menu.

Comment: maybe you should right-click on the line items...  it does work.